# How to determine which stored procedure called another procedure?

Tags: firebird

I have some procedures that calls another procedure with different parameters. Is there a way in that procedure to know who called it? Some kind of stacktrace...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend finding a cleaner way to solve what are you trying to solve, like passing extra parameter to identify what you need to.

Anyway you can use `MON$CALL_STACK` to get, probably, what you're looking for.